# Phonegap contact sort order on ios

Tags: ios, cordova

Does anyone know how to sort the contact data that phonegap liberates from iOS to javascript. The order at the moment is nothing to do with alphabetical sorting. I want to sort on last name.

Here is my contact code:

```
function init_contacts() {
     var fields = [ "name","phoneNumbers"];
     navigator.service.contacts.find(fields, contactSuccess, contactError, '');
}
function contactSuccess(contacts) {
    for (n = 0; n < contacts.length; n++) {
        if (contacts[n].phoneNumbers) {
            for (m = 0; m < contacts[n].phoneNumbers.length; m++) {
                addToMyContacts(contacts[n].name.formatted, contacts[n].phoneNumbers[m].value);
                console.log('Found ' + contacts[n].name.formatted + ' ' + contacts[n].phoneNumbers[m].value);
            }
        }
}
$("#my_contacts").listview("refresh"); 
};

function contactError() {
    navigator.notification.alerter('contactError!');
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this sort by hand in Javascript.

```
var cSort = function(a, b) {
  var aName = a.lastName + ' ' + a.firstName;
  var bName = b.lastName + ' ' + b.firstName;
  return aName < bName ? -1 : (aName == bName ? 0 : 1);
};

function contactSuccess(contacts) {
  contacts = contacts.sort(cSort);
  ...
};
```

Comment: I can't get that to work. I put console.log(aName + ' ' + bName) in the sort function and get undefined undefined undefined undefined out meaning that a.firstName etc is not valid. ACtually, I just checked and it's familyName and givenName, changed but still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: OK, worked out that bit, it needed to be a.name.familyName etc but still not sorting

Comment: OK, fixed it, thanks very much for that mate, it's brilliant!

Comment: Glad to help!  Sorry I wasn't able to test before (been a while since I've had a PhoneGap app together).  Enjoy.

Comment: oh yeh, for the record, the code was perfect as long as you change to a.name.familyName etc, the last bug was in my code

Comment: Glad to hear that.  I did test the sorting function on an array I made up in firebug.

Comment: @Rich I also tried by a.name.familyName but i am unable to fix it, could you please let me know how did you did it.

Answer (score 1):

For more fun and cleaner code you may consider using [lodash](http://lodash.com)

```
contacts = _.sortBy(contacts, ['last_name', 'first_name']);
```

Answer (score 0):

**sorting in js**

function sortByitemName(a, b) {
    var x = a.displayName.toLowerCase();
    var y = b.displayName.toLowerCase();
    return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
    }

```
function onSuccess(contacts) {

contacts.sort(sortByitemName);

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using this method, which is far more efficient (compared to the accepted answer)

```
var cSort=function(a,b){ 
        var an=a.name.formatted.toUpperCase();
        var bn=b.name.formatted.toUpperCase();
        return (an<bn)?-1:(an==bn)?0:1;
    };

function contactSuccess(contacts) {
  contacts = contacts.sort(cSort);
  ...
};
```

1. Contact.name.formatted is more consistent across platforms
2. All names starting with the same letter will be grouped together irregardless of the case. (you can also try it to see).